# UIStackView behaving unpredictably when inside a Container View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistackview

[image: UIStackView in Interface Builder]

The `Stack View H` has two UIViews in it and is constrained to fill the parent UIView. The Grey and Green UIViews within the UIStackView are constrained by width so what I am seeing in Interface Builder is what I am expecting to see.

However, when I run the app I get this:

[image: How it looks in the simulator]

The grey UIView has disappeared (or is hidden behind the green view) and the green view is now full width. I suspect the views are getting stacked on top of each other rather than being distributed, but I don't understand why. The reason I say they are getting stacked on top of each other is because if I change the UIViews to UILabels it becomes clear that that is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Well I worked it out and while I wouldn't call it a bug within Interface Builder, it is certainly a subtlety. In Interface Builder, when you add a new object to a UIStackView from the object library add it to the parent UIView first before dragging it into the UIStackView. If you drag it from the object library directly into the UIStackView "something goes wrong" and that object will not be properly constrained.